# only zipping needed submodules from a module for lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I was trying to put my code on lambda, turns out the code size (layers and deployment package code) is too big for serverless deployment.

One solution is reducing the number of libraries I use and bring uniformity among libraries - for example,  using only a single library for all image processing tasks, rather than multiple.

The second solution is - within that library just keeping those definitions that I actually need. By this, I think I can reduce the whole deployment package size a lot.

I just want to know :

1. Is there one who tried this?
2. Is there any way to know the exact files and code needed from a package respective to my code?

Comment: what is the lambda trigger? what is the frequency?

Comment: well frequency trigger is around 500 calls(max) simultaneously and around 5000 calls in a day, I don't know how it will help to answer my question